# Connect to my home network via VPN from remote

Tags: networking, vpn

I would like to connect my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop to the Windows 10 machine I have at home even when I am travelling abroad. All I want is to access the internet like if I was at home, no need to access the files on the Win machine.

Is there a simple enough guide I can look at or someone able to explain this to me step-by-step?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a Windows question more than an Ubuntu one. Either way, [Tailscale](https://tailscale.com) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! This helps.